# Real world applications of Streaming data

Tags: machine-learning, real-time

Any idea where I can get source of current research topics on data streams with focus on real time applications.

Comment: This is likely a bit broad -- but there's also a problem that there are two different definitions of 'streaming' that might come up in this context -- '(Near) Real Time data', in which the data is being served as it comes in ... but there's also 'streaming protocols' to differentiate from data that's served as files over FTP/HTTP or similar.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the reply! I didn`t get the 'streaming protocols' part.. can you please elaborate further. I was actually thinking from real world applications perspective e.g. say what kind of problems I can give a shot at stock data or social media streams, etc.

Comment: Instead of moving data around as files, some communities have standards for connecting to a socket and issuing commands to select subsets of the data.  Some of those communities refer to them as 'streaming protocols', as the data comes back as a stream, not as a file.  (in some cases, you can also 'watch' for new data, so the protocol also supports NRT (near real time) data, so it'd fit both definitions of 'streaming'.)  One example of a 'streaming protocol' would be [OpenDAP](http://www.opendap.org/about).

Comment: @lesnar can you update your question with those additional information using the edit button. It will make it easier for other trying to help.

Comment: Well there is always the Internet of Things? Plenty of interesting research on efficiently managing these types of streaming data.